# Json and System.JSON in Delphi

Tags: json, delphi

I have this Json

```json
{
  "Sucess": true,
  "Msg": "OK",
  "Ret": {
    "First": 0,
    "Next": true,
    "Total": 60,
    "Itens": [
      {
        "ID": 212121,
        "Name": "uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu",
        "LcID": 9898,
        "Oclao": false,
        "Lal": {
          "ID": 12202,
          "Name": "pppppppppppppppppp",
          "Pais": "Brasil",
          "Dtc": 0.0
        },
        "Subtipo": {
          "ID": 7458,
          "Desc": "mnmnmnmnn"
        },
        "Tipo": {
          "Sit": "cor1",
          "Sitrm": 0,
          "Name": "Shsdfow"
        },
        "Qtde": 0,
        "Qntcoes": 0,
        "Pubum": "adfsdfsdfs",
        "Evias": {
          "arq": {
            "Mo": [
              "site.com"
            ],
            "Moir": [
              "site.com"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "ID": 9797878,
        "Name": "uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu",
        "LcID": 9898,
        "Oclao": false,
        "Lal": {
          "ID": 12332,
          "Name": "pppppppppppppppppp",
          "Pais": "Brasil",
          "Dtc": 0.0
        },
        "Subtipo": {
          "ID": 7458,
          "Desc": "mnmnmnmnn"
        },
        "Tipo": {
          "Sit": "cor1",
          "Sitrm": 0,
          "Name": "Shsdfow"
        },
        "Qtde": 0,
        "Qntcoes": 0,
        "Pubum": "adfsdfsdfs",
        "Evias": {
          "arq": {
            "Mo": [
              "site.com"
            ],
            "Moir": [
              "site.com"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

however, I can only take the values of the first items "Sucess, Msg and Ret"
I'm doing as follows

```
var
 JSONValue, jv: TJSONValue;
 joName: TJSONObject;
 data: TBytes;
 sHtmlResp, sTemp : String;
begin
  sHtmlResp := '[' + sHtmlResp + ']';
  data := TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sHtmlResp);
  JSONValue := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(data, 0);
  for jv in JSONValue as TJSONArray do
   begin
    joName := jv as TJSONObject;
    sTemp:= joName.Get('Msg').JSONValue.Value;
   end;
end;
```

sHtmlResp contains the string json.

I've tried some other ways to get the most unsuccessful field, how do I get the sub-items as "Ret", "Items" and so on.

A detail, had to add '[' ']' in the JSON string I get, otherwise I can not get even the first fields.

Thank!

Comment: Why do you use ASCII?

Comment: Why are you wrapping the JSON with brackets?  You are forcing the entire JSON into an array, which is not necessary.  You are also parsing the JSON as bytes instead of just parsing the string you already have. The conversion to bytes is wasted overhead with no gain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Ret` is a subobject so you need to access it as such.  It has its own values and an array of subobjects, and so on.

Try this:

```
var
 joName, joRet, joItem: TJSONObject;
 joItems: TJSONArray;
 sHtmlResp, sMsg: String;
 bSuccess: Boolean;
begin
  sHtmlResp := ...; // original JSON without added braces around it
  joName := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(sHtmlResp) as TJSONObject;

  bSuccess := joName.GetValue('Success') is TJSONTrue;
  // if you are using Delphi 10 Seattle or later, you can use this instead:
  // bSuccess := (joName.GetValue('Success') as TJSONBool).AsBoolean;

  sMsg := joName.GetValue('Msg').Value;

  joRet := joName.GetValue('Ret') as TJSONObject;
  // use joRet.GetValue() as needed ...

  joItems := joRet.GetValue('Itens') as TJSONArray;
  for i := 0 to joItems.Count-1 do
  begin
    joItem := joItems.Items[i] as TJSONObject;
    // use joItem.GetValue() as needed ...
  end;
end;
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, only in the ''bSuccess := (joName.GetValue('Success') as TJSONBool).AsBoolean;'' returned message E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'TJSONBool' which unit use?

Comment: [`TJSONBool`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONBool) is in the same `System.JSON` unit as all of the other `TJSON...` classes, however it is a new class added in Delphi 10 Seattle, so if you are using an older version of Delphi (you did not specify which version you are actually using) then you will have to check if the `Success` value is a [`TJSONTrue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONTrue) object instead: `bSuccess := joName.GetValue('Success') is TJSONTrue;` I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If each object/sub-object have **unique ObjectID** (name).

The simple way is using this function

```
function ExtractJsonParm(parm:string;h:string):string;
var r:integer;
begin
  r:=pos('"'+Parm+'":',h);
  if r<>0 then
    result := copy(h,r+length(Parm)+4,pos(',',copy(h,r+length(Parm)+4,length(h)))-1)
  else
    result:='';
end;
```

**Usage:**

```
begin
  Writeln(ExtractJsonParm('First',Value));
  Writeln(ExtractJsonParm('Next',Value));
  Writeln(ExtractJsonParm('Total',Value));
end;
```

**Outputs:**

```
0
true
60
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [jsonDoc](https://github.com/stijnsanders/jsonDoc#jsondoc) it would be

```
JSON(sHtmlResp)['Msg']
```

optionally enclosed in `VarToStr` to enforce type (and also silently convert Null to empty string value).

As noted in the comments by Remy: no need to enclose in `[]` as this enforces the outer array.